# how to get the number of bits per symbol?

Tags: matlab, snr, bandwidth

I have a homework question which is:

> A typical telephone channel has the bandwidth of 3100 Hz can support dial-up modems that can variable speeds depending on the quality of the links on both ends of the data call.

> a) (5 points) Assuming the dial-up modem is working at rate of 33.6 kb/s, compute the minimum needed Eb/N0 in dBs.

I answered this question: SNR (db) = 2.76 (almost 3)

> b) (4 points) For part (a), what is the theoretical number of bits per symbol needed to achieve this 33.6 kb/s?

This question is where I got stock
I computed the # of symbols to be 43
then I computed the bandwidth / # of symbols (so, 3100/43) which is almost 72 bits/symbol
I think its **incorrect**

The last question is

> c) (6 points) What are (1) the baud rate and (2) number of bits per symbol used on a standard telephone channel that operates at 33.6 kb/s. Specify the standard model that implements the above specifications for a dial-up modem.

could anyone help me with my solutions?

Comment: Hi Sara! Welcome to DSP.SE. I suggest reviewing the Shannon Channel Capacity formula (Shannon-Hartley Theorem), and then update your question to show your work with that and where exactly you are getting stuck applying it.

Comment: How did you get to 43 symbols?  Can you turn that around?  If the bandwidth is 3100Hz, how many symbols per second can you receive?  If you're receiving that many symbols per second, can you use dimensional analysis to tell you how many bits/symbol you need?